# How to determine the length of poles for a tent

Tags: tents, diy

This tent appears to need just 2 diagonal poles. 
How do I figure out what length diagonal poles I need for an 8 foot x 10 foot (footprint) tent, taking into account the radius of curvature?

[image: Tent image one]

[image: Tent image two]

Comment: Can you explain, via **edit**ing the question, wht those poles are, lying by the tent?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it is a bit hard to tell the model, so here is the process you'll need.

1. Stake the tent out.  Any old stakes will do.
2. With a semi-rigid pole (see below) push this pole through the loops/guides until it is taut.
3. Mark and measure.
4. Once you measure you can order poles from any of a number of sites that sell custom poles.

Semi-rigid poles that can work (depends on tent and diameter of pole)

1. Ratan/Bamboo
2. Fiberglass - You can buy very inexpensive fiberglass rods, just google around.

Comment: Thank you! I will do what you suggest. We also have some extra poles with no tent, and they're not a ready fit, but I can cut the length down a little for the right tension. You can put me on inactive, or whatever.  Thanks again!

Comment: Shouldn't you state that you must actually have "a semi-rigid pole" lying around, and that it is at least as long as the required missing pole?